# Arduino MEGA ADK: read data from USB (not serial)

Tags: serial-port, usb, arduino

What is a way to read some data from the USB device [TelosB Mote](http://www.willow.co.uk/TelosB_Datasheet.pdf)?

It sends packets of 12 octest, and all I want to do is to read two of them. I want to be able to set the transfer speed and the data buffer - I guess.

This board has an integrated USB device port. I've read about the USB [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) 2 library, but I've seen it helps connecting it with an Android phone.

How can I fix this problem?